# How to append to ["foo" : "bar"]

Tags: swift

I have the following in swift 1.2

```
let params = ["foo" : "bar"]
```

I would like to add more to the params so I can end up with the following after a for loop

```
["foo" : "bar", "foo2" : "bar3", "foo3" : "bar3"]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change params because you defined it as a constant.  You need to define it as a variable using var:

```
var params = ["foo" : "bar"]
params["foo2"] = "bar2"
params["foo3"] = "bar3"

println(params) // [foo3: bar3, foo2: bar2, foo: bar]"
```